# Looking for a design pattern & List to store multiple Types (object & integer)

Tags: java, jsp, oop, jakarta-ee, design-patterns

I guess I'm looking for an Design-Pattern but I have a hard time to evaluate which one is the one I need.

I'm going to explain my setup a little and then it may be clear to some1 that has a little more experience.

- When my Application starts I want to create a number of Objects of a class that is in a different `.java` file
- Their lifecycle should only end when the Application is being closed, so I can access them while the application is running from any class within my application
- I need to somehow check if an object with a given attribute exists

  - let's say those objects are user objects with an id & name, I want to be able to check if there is any (and if there is return) an User-Object with the id 1

More precise explanation:

On Startup

- Application looks at database and gets data for all roles in tbl_roles
- Application creates Objects of the class Role with that data

A User logs into the Application

- Application looks at database to see what roles this user has
- Application then maps the Role Objects to the User Object (the User Object has a List in which the Role Objects are stored)
- in order to do that the Application must have access to the Role Objects created on Startup

Right now I read in data from my database, & create the Objects using that data, but when leaving that function those Objects lifecycle is up but I want them to stay till my application closes.

I'm working on an web application using Java & JSP & Apache Shiro Framework

I have this class that runs at application start and I thought I might do this here?

`Startup.java`

```
public class Startup implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Startup.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Code here is executed on application startup
        // create singleton object to get all roles/rights from db
        Roles_rights tmp = Roles_rights.getInstance();
        System.out.println("\nStartup.java role_list.size = " + role_list.size());

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Code here is executed on application close
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

`Roles_rights.java`

```
public static Roles_rights getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new Roles_rights();
        instance.get_rights_of_role();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void get_rights_of_role(){
    // create object of startup class so I can access the setter method
    Startup startup = new Startup();

    // here I query my database for all roles   

    // add role to list of roles
    startup.set_RoleObject(role);
}
```

When I reach the line

```
System.out.println("\nStartup.java role_list.size = " + role_list.size());
```

Of `contextInitialized` Method it prints out that the list is empty `(size = 0)`
but it just got filled with objects.

The Problem here is (in my eyes) that there is no main class with a `main` function that will run all the way throughout the lifetime of the application.
Every Java class is just a servlet or contributes to a servlet used in my application.

The only way that I see to store data across multiple classes is a user session attribute (but the application itself doent have a session I guess).

**Solution:**

I solved the first part:

`Startup.java`

```
public class Startup implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Startup.class);
    private static Startup instance = null;

    private List<Role> role_list = new ArrayList<Role>();

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // create singleton object to get all roles/rights from db
        getInstance();
        System.out.println("\nStartup.java role_list.size = " + instance.role_list.size());
    }

    public static Startup getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Startup();
            instance.get_rights_of_role();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    // get the list of RoleObjects
    public List<Role> get_RoleObjects(){
        return role_list;
    }

}
```

User.java

```
public class User {
    public int user_id;
    public String username;
    public List<List<?>> roles = new ArrayList<List<?>>(3);

    // get instance of Startup to access role_list
    Startup instance = Startup.getInstance();

    public void add_roles(User user, List<List<Integer>> user_roles){
        // instantiate array list
        roles.add(new ArrayList<Role>());      // stores Role Object
        roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
        roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());

        System.out.println("\nUser.java: startup.get_RoleObjects().size = " + instance.get_RoleObjects().size());
        for(Role role : instance.get_RoleObjects()){
            if(user_roles.get(0).contains(role.role_id)){
                System.out.println("\nUser has role " + role.role_name );
            }
            System.out.println("\nUser dosnt have role" + role.role_name");
        }
    }
}
```

**Issue 2**
The second thing I'm looking for is a List that stores Object of multiple types.
So far I have a List that stores 3 List of Integers:

```
public List<List<Integer>> roles = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(3);
roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

What I really want is a List that stores object of a class in the first List and Integers in the 2 other Lists like this:

```
public List<List<Object>> roles = new ArrayList<List<Object>>(3);
roles.add(new ArrayList<Role>());    //error here (Role is a class inside my application)
roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); //error here
roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); //error here
```

**Issue 2**

I ended up using

```
public List<List<?>> roles = new ArrayList<List<?>>(3);
roles.add(new ArrayList<Role>());
roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

And that seems to do the trick as far as the basic setup goes. Now in the two inner Integer List I want to add integer values from another List but that's causing errors now:

```
List<List<Integer>> user_roles // comes from a different class to this method
user.roles.get(1).addAll(user_roles.get(1)); // error
user.roles.get(2).addAll(user_roles.get(2)); // error
```

Error is:

```
no suitable method found for allAll(List<Integer>)
  method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends CAP#1>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; List<Integer> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends CAP#1>)
  method Collection.addAll(Collection<? extends CAP#1>) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; List<Integer> cannot be converted to Collection<? extends CAP#1>)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
```

**Solution to Issue 2:**

Created a List of Objects

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> listOfUnknownList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

Added 3 Lists of type Object

```
listOfUnknownList.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
listOfUnknownList.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
listOfUnknownList.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
```

Filled those Lists with data

```
listOfUnknownList.get(0).add(role);                     // Adds a Role Object
listOfUnknownList.get(1).add(user_roles.get(1).get(i)); // Adds an Integer
listOfUnknownList.get(2).add(user_roles.get(2).get(i)); // Adds an Integer
```

Comment: added the error message in my question at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay well you don't actually want to find a design pattern or store things in a list. What you really want is to solve a problem using code. You should tell us what that problem is.

To your problems though: The application initialisation is in effect your "Main". It is the first part of your application which will receive control from the application container. Now it is worth bearing in mind that your JSP will act as the main driver of your application (or maybe some other event... like a DB update for example), so really your application context should just setup the information/state required by those threads in order to serve the actions of the user.

**EDIT** From your comment below you are worried about how your scope will work without a main. It is almost exactly the same:

```
public class Application implements javax.servlet.ServletContextListener {

    private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Startup.class);

    private Map<String, User> users = new HashMap<>();
    private UserRolesDb userRolesDb = new UserRolesDb("localhost:4412");

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Code here is executed on application startup
        userRolesDb.connect();
        for(User user: validateResult(userRolesDb.getAll()) ) {
            users.put(user.getId(), user);
        }
    }

    public getUserRoles(){
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(users);
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        // Code here is executed on application close
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}
```

So you can see above that I access the DB build the users map and allow an accessor to return an non-mutable view of the map (read only). The `Application` instance is started by the application container and will be around for the lifetime as will any objects that it references. This idea is fairly rough around the edges but it is only there to illustrate that there is not much to worry about in terms of keeping your objects alive, just keep a reference to the objects in the `Application` class (or in another instance that Application references).

Regarding your compilation issues it looks like `user_roles.get(1)` returned a `List<Integer>` which is not as expected... Suggesting that `user.roles.get(1)` is not of type `List<Integer>`.

Given your description of wanting to check if there is a User with a particular ID though I would question why you are not using `Map<String, User>`. The list of lists look very unnecessary to me, but cannot say for certain as I am not clear on what your goal is.

Last bit of help:

```
// This list contains a list. That list has ONE TYPE. It can
// only store one kind of list.
// I cannot add a List<Role> to it.
List<List<?>> listOfListsOfUnknownTypes = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

// This list contains a list. That list has ONE TYPE. It can
// only store lists of OBJECTS.
// I cannot add a List<Role> to it. I cannot add a List<Integer> to it.
// I can only add List<Object> to it.
// I CAN add objects to the lists inside the list.
List<List<Object>> listOfListsOfObjects = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

// Not sure if will compile okay actually
// This list contains unknown lists. All you know about them 
// is that they should be some kind of list. You don't know 
// what types of objects the list contains. Or even the type of 
// list. 
// BUT it is ONE type of list because you are using the CAPTURE '?'
List<? extends List<?>> listOfUnknownList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

// I think that what you want is this:
List<List<Object>> listOfUnknownList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
```

The fact that you are doing this kind of thing means that you need to redesign your solution. This is bad. You are attempting to index across lists based on the roles.

Also in your addRoles method you should be only using the `roles` member on `this` object. What I would do:

```
public void add_roles(List<List<Integer>> user_roles){
    // instantiate array list
    for(Role role : instance.get_RoleObjects()){
        if(user_roles.get(0).contains(role.role_id)){
            // Make roles a List<Role> only
            roles.add(role); // Use the roles object on THIS
            System.out.println("\nUser has role " + role.role_name );
        }
        System.out.println("\nUser dosnt have role" + role.role_name");
    }
}
```

Comment: added a more detailed explaination in my initial post

Comment: regarding my error: I do have the `roles.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());` which is of type Integer and assign a List to it so it should work I thought

Comment: But what is `user_roles`?

Comment: `user_roles` is a list that I get from a database-query when the user logs into the application (I get his roles along with 2 other values related to that role ("the place" where is is able to execute rights of that role)) And after that I try to find the Role Objects that are mathing his roles (the ones I got from the query) and assign those role objects to his user object

Comment: updated the initial post to address that the list is getting filled via a setter method but just after that seems to be emtpty again (i fill it from a different class -> as I need to create an instance of this class in order to adress the setter method, may that be the cause of the list appearing to be empty?)

Comment: The error message says that you are attempting to a `List<Object>` to a `List<Integer>`. This is why I asked about the `user_roles`.

You are also using `role_list` without having declared it. Or at least in your posted example it is not there. Can you not just post your code?

Comment: just posted a reply with my code. I dont get why I cant add Objects of class Role to a List of Type Role

Comment: I would suggest that you continue to work more on this issue yourself. When you have `specific` problems with areas of the code you should come back. Also you should provide a small complete compilable example of the problem when asking a question.

Comment: I do have a specific problem right now as I cannot create a List that will hold 3 lists of different types that I can fill

Comment: See update. You are obviously not very experienced with Java. Try working through some object oriented tutorials to see how to break down your problems a little better. Good luck with it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to use a map as collection for you role instance and keep you role map in application scope.
Map will allow you set/get role instance based on id and application scope will keep your instances live and available through out application.

**Edit:**
Create a wrapper Class which look similar to this

```
public class RoleWrapper
(
private Role role;
private int value1;
private int value2;

/*
 getter setter here
*/
}
```

Now on startup of application inside contextInitialized() method , create a map

```
Map<String,RoleWrapper> roles =new HashMap<>();
```

Now read each role and its associeted two integer values from DB , create instance of RoleWrapper , set all three values in it and put it in roles map where map key is role id.

after finishing above iteration , put you roles map in application scope.

Comment: so instead of `public List<List<?>> roles = new ArrayList<List<?>>(3);` you would use a map right? But how would such a map look like?

Comment: but a map can only hold 2 values but I need 2 in this case. 1 Object of class Role & 2 integer values